# How does YouTube test their video editing platform?

Tags: automated-testing, test-strategy

How should I approach the task of constructing automation to test a video platform?

For example, how does YouTube tests their video editor. Can this even be done with automation?

Are there existing tools to achieve this or do I need to write it from scratch?

Comment: I'm not sure that anybody knows the testing methods of youtube.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have good experience with automation for enterprise software like routers and storage devices, but I've never had a chance to test video editing platforms. How should one start designing an automation platform to test the service from a user's point of view and verify the video is created correctly? Are there any existing tools?

Comment: There are lots of criteria you could test such a software against. One of them is performance: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/how-do-you-stress-test-a-video-streaming-app.

Comment: @dzieciou That's a good point. But I'm more concerned with the video content being correct.

Comment: @thedp What do you mean by correct? With respect to what?